# What are the objective benefits of allowing display name changes?

Tags: user-behavior

Stack Exchange allows its users to change their display name [once every 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38180/295232). This was a little surprising for me; on most previous sites where I was an active member, you picked a (permanent) username during registration. It often (but not always) needed to be unique (though that might be because you also used it to login). But once you chose a name, you were basically stuck with it; to change it, you'd need to sign up again (and thus losing your account history) or write a *very* compelling story to the site administrators with a request to change your name. On those sites, you'd still had plenty of personalization options in your avatar and/or signatures under your posts.

I can imagine valid use cases for wanting to change your display name; if you signed up as a teenager with a name like UnicornLover1234, and you want to change it to something more professional since that better suites the current phase of your life. Another example would be a gender change; that's something people change their *real* name for, but it's not done lightly and takes a lot of paperwork.

The main drawback of the current system on Stack Exchange is that, at least for me, it's sometimes hard to keep track of users, especially since they can have different names across the different sites in the network (but that is not the main point of this question, since it only applies to Stack Exchange). Sometimes you see a user where their reputation and/or the way the write indicate that they are long-time users and your paths might have crossed before, but it frustrates me a bit that I don't recognize them. Just like you meet someone in real life who you fail to recognize from previous encounters; that always embarrasses me.

Of course, if a user temporarily changes their name to match the current 'season' (e.g. Halloween), but does it in a way that they're still recognizable as their former self, that doesn't cause any confusion.

It could perhaps be argued that Stack Exchange wants it users to focus on *content*, not on the users who are posting them. But this is simply not how the human mind/a community works, not when focused on objective Q&A like the technology Stack Exchange sites, but especially not when it comes to discussions on Meta.

Therefore, I was wondering: are there any **objective benefits** of allowing users to change their display names? The answer may apply to a specific kind of online community (e.g. one where anonymity is very important), that's fine.

<sub>Note: I'm not asking Stack Exchange to change their policy; I'd ask such a question on Meta Stack Exchange but I guess I've learned to live with the current system.</sub>

Answer (score 12):

You've touched on two good reasons why you'd want to allow name changes on a site (not just Stack Exchange).

1. Making your user name more "professional" or perhaps a better term would be "appropriate".

   For a site like Stack Overflow which attracts both professional and amateur programmers it could be that you signed up while you were still dabbling with programming (or whatever the topic is) so a funny and/or frivolous name would be not seen as inappropriate. However, if you decided to take things further then you'd want to be seen as a more serious contributor, and if your past contributions were valuable you'd want them still to be associated with your account.
2. Stack Overflow *does* emphasise the content rather than who posted it so it deliberately de-emphasises the name of the contributor. In that sense it doesn't care what your name is (within reason) so it doesn't make sense to disallow name changes.

Other valid reasons for changing user names:

1. Anonymity. If you signed up for the site and used your real name as your user name you may now have decided to that you're not comfortable with that and want to become "user1234" (or whatever).
2. Name change. You still want to use your real name but this has changed for some reason (marriage, divorce, adoption, etc.) and naturally you want your online presence to match this.

Yes, allowing name changes can potentially make life difficult for other contributors, but if only one of the name or avatar changes at any one time then this disruption is kept to a minimum.

From a moderation point of view we have the user account **id** and a history of moderator actions on that account so the name currently displayed is less important.